# Unexpected result in assignment function for a calculator

Tags: c++, function, class, variable-assignment

I am currently trying to tackle exercise 2 of chapter 7 of "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup.

I have to implement an assignment operation in the code. The code is 500 lines long, so I will omit the segments that I have already tested thoroughly and I know are not the cause of the problem.

The problem lies in the `assignment()` function, more specifically if I `cout` the value of `d` after the `set_value()`, the correct value is outputted, but a different one is returned. For example:

If I input:

`let c = 3;`

The code will output `"= 3"` as expected, but then if I go on with an assignment operation typing:

`c = 2`

The code outputs `-1.45682e+144`, which is different than 2.

The code is as follows:

```cpp
class Token {
public:
    char kind;        // what kind of token
    double value;     // for numbers: a value 
    string name;      // for names: name itself
    Token(char ch) : kind(ch), value(0) {}
    Token(char ch, double val) : kind(ch), value(val) {}
    Token(char ch, string n) : kind(ch), name(n) {}
};

class Variable {
public:
    string name;
    double value;
    Variable(string n, double v) :name(n), value(v) { }
};

void set_value(string s, double d)
// set the Variable named s to d
{
    for (int i = 0; i < var_table.size(); ++i)
        if (var_table[i].name == s) {
            var_table[i].value = d;
            return;
        }
    error("set: undefined variable ", s);
}

double assignment(string name)
{
    Token t = ts.get();
    if (t.kind != '=') error("= missing in declaration of ", name);

    double d = expression(); 
    set_value(name, d);
    return d;
}
```

`ts.get()` returns an appropriate token containing `kind` AND `value` if it finds a string or double in the input, or just `kind` for other literals that can be expressed as characters (eg operators, or in this case, `'='`).

`expression()` calculates and returns any combination of addictions, subtractions, multiplications, divisions, and moduli that it finds, and also supports parenthesis, `sqrt()`, and `pow()`. It works perfectly.

Since I have already checked whether `name` has already been declared through a `let` statement before calling `assignment()`, I only call `set_value()` which changes the `value` member of the variable named `s` to `d`.

`var_table` is a `vector` with all variables I declared.

I've been over this problem for hours, but couldn't solve it. The scientific notation weird number output is just so random, and somehow happens between `set_value()` working correctly and `return d;`.

full code can be found here if you're curious https://collabedit.com/5pa6h

Comment: If a `Token` object is constructed with a `string` input, the `value` member is left *uninitialized* unless `set_value()` is called on that object later.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. "warning: control reaches end of non-void function". It's interesting that you think that the problem occurs between `set_value()` and `return d`, since there's a lot that happens between `return d` and the `cout` that could also go wrong. Follow the `return d` to see where it goes. (Spoiler alert; It is thrown away.)

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, i was able to solve the problem and learn something new! @RaymondChen

Comment: Please post the answer to help others who encounter the same problem in the future.